# No user/host info in terminal prompt

Tags: command-line

I open terminal and see only this:

```
$
```

as to where I expect it to look like

```
user@host:~$
```

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHIC9.png)

Do you have any idea, what I need to do to get the regular shell prompt back? I am using Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 10):

You seem to have changed to a very basic shell for that user (e.g. `/bin/sh`). Try changing to a more common shell, e.g. Bash, using

```
chsh -s /bin/bash username
```

On a regular Ubuntu installation, the shell prompt is decorated in the `.bashrc` file in your home directory. However, not all shells are sourcing/supporting that file/configuration.

For more details on this decoration in Bash, see the occurrences of `PS1` in the `~/.bashrc` file.